# Why my answer to question 13048 about Imamah is deleted?

Tags: discussion, support

This is my answer:

https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/13065/67

I used verses about رسل that is not limited to prophets. but instead they can be prophet or Imam.

I do not understand why this is deleted. it is answering the question with different possible points.

It is good practice to mod who wants to delete a post leave a comment saying the reason.

Answer (score 1):

It had content problem. The answer had to be filtered out all that text. It wasn't clear and specific.

I did choose [Looks Good](https://islam.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/6053) when it landed in my Low Quality Review queue and I standby it because although it had a lot of noise and incoherence but it did get around partially and somewhat unconvincingly answer the question. Therefore it didn't deserve a delete but DV and a constructive critique would have been in-place.

**Remedy:**

- Show it some editing love
- Clean it up
- Link the facts
- Make them coherent
- **Make sure you make it obvious and evident why the fact that is being stated is relevant to the answer.**

Do that and get back to meta to ask the community if the issues has been resolved and the answer can be undeleted.

Comment: Answer improved. is it OK now?